Highlight js import not working in lit components (es / eslint issue)
Have this piece of code in a lit component;
import {LitElement, html, property, CSSResultArray, TemplateResult, unsafeCSS} from 'lit-element';
import { customElement, query } from 'lit/decorators.js';
import {styles} from './nile-code-block.css';
import NileElement from '../internal/nile-element';
import hljs from 'highlight.js';

While rendering this I get the error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/__wds-outside-root__/2/node_modules/highlight.js/lib/index.js' does not provide an export named 'default' (at index.js:2:8)
This comes out to be the code for source file when checked:
//https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_writing_dual_packages_while_avoiding_or_minimizing_hazards
import HighlightJS from '/__wds-outside-root__/2/node_modules/highlight.js/lib/index.js';
export { HighlightJS };
export default HighlightJS;


I've tried uninstalling and installing again (yarn add highlight.js)
Tried using it in a sample project on vite with vanilla.js, works fine there.

How exactly is ESLint involved here?
